# Rotate in the y axis Quaternion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am controlling an object's rotation with the function `Quaternion.FromToRotation`. But unfortunately it is rotating in all 3 axes. Can someone help me so I can rotate only in the y axis and x & z should not be affected?

```
private Quaternion currentRot;
private Vector3 startPos;
private bool offsetSet;

public GameObject Ball;

void Update()
{
        SetOffsets();
 
        Vector3 closestPoint = Vector3.Normalize(transform.position - Ball.transform.position);
        robot.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(startPos, closestPoint) * currentRot;
    
}

void SetOffsets()
    {
        if (offsetSet)
            return;
 
        startPos = Vector3.Normalize(transform.position - Ball.transform.position);
        currentRot = Ball.transform.rotation;
 
        offsetSet = true;
    }
```

Comment: You could change the rotation.x or .y or .z with a Lerp and a and just change the value

Comment: global y axis or local y axis?

Comment: local y axis. Just that x and z of my object should not be affected. Right now I am using LateUpdate() function to keep x and z not affected but I am looking for better solutions.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If my answer helped, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach is needed. Instead of keeping a direction to indicate your starting offset, keep a [signed angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html) to the local forward from a particular direction related to the ball, rotated around the local up. That particular direction is the direction of the ball, [projected](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) on the plane normal to robot's up, or in other words, "flattened" so it is no longer locally above or below the robot.

```
private Quaternion startRot; // currentRot is a misleading name
private float startAngleOffset;
private bool offsetSet;

[SerializeField] GameObject Ball;

void SetOffsets()
{
    if (offsetSet)
        return;
 
    Vector3 thisToBall = Ball.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector3 robotUp = robot.transform.up;
    Vector3 flattenedToBall = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(thisToBall, robotUp);
    Vector3 startAngleOffset = Vector3.SignedAngle(flattenedToBall, 
            robot.transform.forward, robotUp);
        
    currentRot = Ball.transform.rotation;
 
    offsetSet = true;
}
```

Then, when it comes time to set the rotation, do another projection of the ball's direction, then [use](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) this signed angle to [find the direction forward should be](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html). Then use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to set the rotation accordingly.

Altogether:

```
private Quaternion startRot;
private float startAngleOffset;
private bool offsetSet;

[SerializeField] GameObject Ball;

void Update()
{
    SetOffsets();

    Vector3 robotUp = robot.transform.up;
    Vector3 flattenedToBall = GetFlattenedToBall();
    Vector3 robotForwardDir = Quaternion.AngleAxis(startAngleOffset, robotUp)
            * flattenedToBall;

    robot.transform.rotation = LookRotation(robotForwardDir, robotUp);
}


void SetOffsets()
{
    if (offsetSet)
        return;
 
    Vector3 flattenedToBall = GetFlattenedToBall();
    Vector3 startAngleOffset = Vector3.SignedAngle(flattenedToBall, 
            robot.transform.forward, robot.transform.up);
    
    currentRot = Ball.transform.rotation;
 
    offsetSet = true;
}

Vector3 GetFlattenedToBall()
{
    Vector3 thisToBall = Ball.transform.position - transform.position;
    Vector3 flattenedToBall = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(thisToBall, robot.transform.up);
}
```